# Getting rid of browser restart on plugin installation

Tags: plugins, browser, restart, firebreath

I have been working on a browser plugin for windows which involves displaying camera output in browser. Presently I'm working on Windows 7. After plugin installation, I want to start the plugin immediately without restarting the browser. I noticed that as soon as plugin is registered, it started working in Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312 as well as in Internet Explorer 9. But it fails to do so in Mozilla Firefox 18.0.1. Can anyone help me solve this problem of restarting the browser after plugin installation. And will this problem occur in MacOS as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a navigator.plugins.refresh(false); in javascript to tell the browser to rescan the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Explore /Installer/js -folder in FireBreath sources